# Why onDurationChanged is not called in Flutter ios?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, audio, audio-player

I'm using  `audioplayers: 1.1.0` library to play audio from url

I use the `onDurationChanged` method to get the audio file length. This is working perfectly on `android` but in `iOS` the `onDurationChanged` is not getting called.
I tried all solutions available in the internet. Noting helps as expected. Your help wil save my day.

> Note: If I use

```
 player.play(UrlSource('theme_01.mp3'));
```

Now works fine. **But If I use**

```
 player.play(UrlSource('https://www.kozco.com/tech/LRMonoPhase4.mp3');
```

onDurationChanged is not working

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Audio Player'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final player = AudioPlayer();
  bool isPlaying = false;
  Duration duration = Duration.zero;
  Duration position = Duration.zero;

  String formatTime(int seconds) {
    return '${(Duration(seconds: seconds))}'.split('.')[0].padLeft(8, '0');
  }

  final AudioContext audioContext = AudioContext(
    iOS: AudioContextIOS(
      defaultToSpeaker: true,
      category: AVAudioSessionCategory.ambient,
      options: [
        AVAudioSessionOptions.defaultToSpeaker,
        AVAudioSessionOptions.mixWithOthers,
      ],
    ),
    android: AudioContextAndroid(
      isSpeakerphoneOn: true,
      stayAwake: true,
      contentType: AndroidContentType.sonification,
      usageType: AndroidUsageType.assistanceSonification,
      audioFocus: AndroidAudioFocus.none,
    ),
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    AudioPlayer.global.setGlobalAudioContext(audioContext);

    player.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((state) {
      setState(() {
        isPlaying = state == PlayerState.playing;
      });
    });

    player.onDurationChanged.listen((newDuration) {
      setState(() {
        duration = newDuration;
      });
    });

    player.onPositionChanged.listen((newPosition) {
      setState(() {
        position = newPosition;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Slider(
              min: 0,
              max: duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
              value: position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                final position = Duration(seconds: value.toInt());
                player.seek(position);
                player.resume();
              },
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 25,
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (isPlaying) {
                        player.pause();
                      } else {
                         // player.play(UrlSource('theme_01.mp3'));
// If I use local audio works fine. But If I use the below audio url onDurationChanged is not called.

                        player.play(UrlSource('https://www.kozco.com/tech/LRMonoPhase4.mp3'));
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                ),
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 25,
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.stop),
                    onPressed: () {
                      player.stop();
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(formatTime(position.inSeconds)),
                  Text(formatTime((duration - position).inSeconds)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```